# Styling in IE and Edge

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, accordion, microsoft-edge

I am working on accordion which style is written inside the company.
My initial output Chrome which look like this

[image]

where the down arrow is on the right corner. It's also fine in FireFox,
but when we try to show in on IE and Edge, the arrow moves to the left side.

[image]

[image]

Here is my inspecting on following elements:

header in accordion

```css
.accordion .accordion-header {
    font-family: "MuseoSans-300", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.15em;
    line-height: 1.4;
    color: #6d8191;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 15px 30px 15px 0;
    position: relative;
    border-top: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}
```

Arrow in accordion:

```css
.accordion .accordion-header .accordion-arrow {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    right: -3px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transition: transform 0.25s, -webkit-transform 0.25s;
}
```

Any suggestion to fix this for IE, and Edge?

Comment: Can you also include your HTML, as well?

Comment: Sure, but it includes some freemaker tags since the back-end team are working with Java.

Comment: The generated markup that the browser sees would be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with Edge 12+

```
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
  .selector { property:value; } 
}
```

[read on @supports as a rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/css/supports-at-rule)

so do just alignment as so :

```
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
      .accordion .accordion-header .accordion-arrow {  right:value; } 
    }
```

Explorer 11+ Browsers (I haven't tested it)

```
_:-ms-fullscreen, :root .selector { property:value; }
```